# Convert Date to UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, unix, date, timestamp

I'm having a date format of `Jun 26, '12`.
`strtotime()` converts proper date string, and this string results in a blank output.
This can be solved but I can only think of ugly ways of doing it.

Any ideas for converting this date format to UNIX timestamp elegantly?

Comment: Are you after a php only solution?

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Also tell us what have you tried so far? Post SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Comment: @AleksandrKravets PHP...I tried preg_replace using the PHP manual.Unfortunately,it seems I haven't quite understood it.

Comment: @user1425322 please add the php tag then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about this `strtotime('Jun 26,12');`

Comment: I was able to use this by exploding and then using strtotime() directly..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I used `DateTime::createFromFormat` works well for me.. more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 0):

Um, `s/'/20/g'`?  Followed by `strtotime()`?

Comment: Interestingly, this is isomorphic to the answer that got accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```php
$string = 'April 26,\'12';
echo strtotime(preg_replace('/(\w+) (\d+),\'(\d+)/i', '$2 $1 20$3', $string));
```

Based on example from [php.net](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-examples)

Comment: I guess if it is separated with more spaces or tabs, you can try this: echo strtotime(preg_replace('/(\w+)[\s]{1,}(\d+),[\s]{0,}\'[\s]{1,}(\d+)/i', '$2 $1 20$3', $string));