# How to convert the date 11/03/2013(i.e. 11 March 2013) to unix timestamp in php?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I want to convert the date in above format to the equivalent Unix Timestamp. I searched a lot but couldn't get any solution. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You couldn't have searched much: `strtotime()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Try this strtotime('11/03/2013');

Comment: Do some basic search dude before posting Question : ) -

Comment: Also try searching google and stackoverflow. This question has been asked so many times.

Comment: This question has been asked already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324195/convert-date-to-unix-timestamp

Comment: Check this out.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12278943/1288198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$pieces = explode("/", "11/03/2013");
echo strtotime($pieces[1]."/".$pieces[0]."/".$pieces[2]);
```

Comment: (you need to provide the date in a valid form (MM/dd/YY))

Comment: yeah..the only one who sees that dd/mm/yy not work with strtotime

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this `strtotime($date);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this strtotime('11/03/2013');

Comment: Try this.. `date(d/m/Y, strtotime("11/03/2013"));` And see what you get..

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime('Jun 26,12');
```

That will sort all of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

***if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.***

Try using this...

```
strtotime( str_replace( '/', '-', '11/03/2013') ) );
```

You can find more details **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12278943/1288198)**...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very spezial Format, then with DateTime

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('11-2013.03', 'd-Y.m')->getTimestamp()
```

if its a normal Date-Format, then with strtotime()

Answer (score 0):

PHP >= 5.2

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '11/03/2013');
echo $date->format('U');
```

PHP >= 5.3

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '11/03/2013');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```